# Multiple Left joins off of an id

Tags: mysql

I am not too advanced when it comes to SQL manipulation. I have the following 4 tables from a banners system to advertise my blogs:

```
banners 
-id
-other irrelevant data

clicks
-id
-bid (banner id) 
-other irrelevant data

exits (people who clicked on the banner and never used the blog or registered an account)
-id
-bid

postregistered (used the banner and register to the blog)
-id
-bid
```

Now I want to generate a simple report to show me the `total number of clicks`, `exits` and `reg's` for each banner.

I tried this:

```
SELECT COUNT(c.id) as clicks, COUNT(e.id) as exits, COUNT(r.id) as reg
FROM banners b
LEFT JOIN clicks c
ON c.bid = b.id
LEFT JOIN exits e
ON e.bid = b.id
LEFT JOIN registered r
ON r.bid = b.id
GROUP BY b.name
```

But it just makes mysql kill my processor and never completes, there is not enough data for it to be a heavy query.

Please can you help me, sorry if this seems very basic.

EDIT:

I can run each Left join own its own and get the correct result but I would rather run this as a single query

Comment: Execute `EXPLAIN SELECT ...` and post result and table structures.

Comment: Have you tried not using the table names as aliases?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem that you are facing is a small cartesian product for each banner.  In simple terms, the banner id is not sufficient for linking the tables.

Say you have 10 banners.  Each banner has 100 clicks.  Of these clicks, 50 are exits and 50 are registered.  You are probably thinking that you are going to get something like 1000 rows out of this.

No, you are getting the product of all of these:  10 * 100 * 50 * 50 = 2,500,000.  That's a lot of processing.

You need some sort of user id to track users from from clicks through the exits and registers.  Alternatively, you can pre-aggregate your queries:

```
select b.bid, b.name, numclicks, numexits, numreg
from banner b left outer join
     (select bid, count(*) as numclicks
      from clicks
      group by bid
     ) c left outer join
     on c.bid = b.bid join
     (select bid, count(*) as numexits
      from exits
      group by bid
     ) e
     on e.bid = b.bid left outer join
     (select bid, count(*) as numreg
      from postregistered
      group by bid
     ) r
     on r.bid = b.bid
```

Comment: +1 Well said. Here is an example you can add to your answer. http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/a1b47/2

Comment: This worked and only took 239ms to process, much better then having to run 3 separate queries. Thank you :D